# MinGW: Cannot find -llibSDLmain and -llibSDL

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

Why MinGW cannot find libSDLmain and libSDL? I'm using SDL 1.2.15, CLion and CMake.

cmakelists.txt:

```
project(raycaster)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/cpplib/SDL-1.2.15")
find_package(SDL REQUIRED)
include_directories("C:/cpplib/SDL-1.2.15/include")

add_executable(raycaster main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(raycaster mingw32 libSDL libSDLmain)
```

SDL::SDL also doesn't help

Comment: Is there a `FindSDL.cmake` in your `"C:/cpplib/SDL-1.2.15"`?

Comment: it is in CMake dir

Comment: After `find_package(SDL REQUIRED)` you have `SDL_LIBRARY` variable, so use it: `target_link_libraries(raycaster mingw32 ${SDL_LIBRARY})`. The IMPORTED taret ``SDL::SDL`` has appeared only in CMake 3.19: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindSDL.html